# Client-side-validation colorbox form

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, colorbox, client-side-validation

I am using `gem 'rails', '3.2.8'` I build a contact form following this tutorial:

http://matharvard.ca/posts/2011/aug/22/contact-form-in-rails-3/

it works when I go to /contact now I have added `gem 'client_side_validations'` it works as well on contact. I now have put that form in a colorbox using `gem 'colorbox-rails', '~> 0.0.9'`

The form works still, but now it does not validate as you go. So if you click submit it goes to the contact page with the validations. Has anyone ran into this? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up going with

http://www.livevalidation.com/

it is really easy to setup. All I had to do is add the javascript to the head

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/assets/livevalidation_standalone.js"></script>
```

and then tell it which to validate

```
var message_name = new LiveValidation('message_name');
message_name.add( Validate.Presence );
```

**EDIT 1**

I found this, you can incorporate it into your rails app

https://github.com/richpoirier/livevalidation

Hope this helps someone!